# Python Regex in matching multiple formats

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to match some criteria in my sentence. I could come up with a regex pattern, but unfortunately though some are matching but still it is not matching properly for others. 
In a sentence, I need to keep the alphanumeric string only while keeping those strings which have "-" inbetween and " ' " apostrophe. Example

- hello
- hello-world
- year's

my regex is: `(?=\S*|['-])([a-zA-Z0-9'-]+)`

currently the above regex is matching "---" (should not be correct) but not matching "year's"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-'][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*
```

Note that `(?=\S*|['-])` is an always true assertion since `\S*` matches the empty string.

Comment: fantastic ... this is what did the job, so to get the required strings I just had to enclose within the brackets - `([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-'][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)` .. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex

```
^(?=\S*[-'])(?!\S*[-']{2,})([-a-zA-Z0-9']+)$
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLu4xu/2). It ensures that the string has at least 1 [-'] and they are not consecutive

Comment: this is actually not matching my first example. i.e "hello" and also other alphanumeric such as "hello123". though matching "hello-world" and "world's"